# git rebase command broken - mangled output

Tags: git, rebase

For some reason `git rebase -i <SHA>` stopped working for me.

I have been using git-rebase to cleanup my feature branches before merges happily for quite some time now, but as of today I only get mangled output in the interactive editor popup...

Using an example repository:

```
git clone git@github.com:philsquared/Catch.git
cd Catch/
git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

My git-editor pops up with the following mangled content:

```
# Note that empty commits are commented out
ebase will be aborted.
#
edit the commit message
# e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# d, drop = remove commit
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
```

Note that there are no empty-commits in the given history-frame (HEAD~5).

I'm using git 2.13.2 on Manjaro/Arch-Linux and here is what I tried so far without any success:

- Reinstalling git from scratch (`pacman -Rdd git; pacman -Scc; pacman -S git`)
- Rebooting the system
- Tested with different repositories
- Deleting/Renaming my ~/.gitconfig
- Executing command as different users
- Changing locale from de_DE.UTF-8 to en_US.UTF-8
- Using different editors (Atom, Nano, Kate)

I'm at a complete loss here...

## Update

**Its working again!**

I was able to track down the culprit to be related to kernel version 4.12.1 (on manjaro/arch-linux). This issue only seems to happen when running with this kernel version, with kernel 4.11.10 everything seems to be fine and working as expected, eg. for the above example I get:

```
pick 3083de9 Fix typo in README
pick 8d380a7 added 'args' argument parser library
pick a53ea30 Eliminate some work when results won't be reported.
pick 106d7e2 Initialize JunitReporter::unexpectedExceptions in constructor
pick 8ebe94c Added NOLINT annotations to selectively suppress clang_tidy warnings

# Rebase 431e8d0..8ebe94c onto 431e8d0 (5 commands)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick = use commit
# r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# d, drop = remove commit
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
```

*Might this be a kernel-bug or only an issue on my specific system/configuration with the 4.12.1 version?*

Additional information that might be usfull in unterstanding this issue:

- OS: Linux
- Kernel 4.12.1-1
- Distribution: Manjaro
- GIT: 2.13.2
- Root-Filesystem: BTRFS on LUKS-Partition

Comment: Could it be that your commit message are not formed like "<subject><emptyline><detailed description>" or has some special symbols?

Comment: Is it all content of the file? No commits?

Comment: Nope, sadly this is the whole content, not commits. Special symbols in commit messages seem unlikely because rebase stopped working on all repositories I tried; all my local clones that worker the day before and some I freshly cloned from github just to find a solution or working edge-case. :(

Comment: I think I might have found the culprit: Booted into 4.11 kernel and it was working, booted back into 4.12 kernel and it was broken again. Will now boot back into 4.11 and update my initial post if it is still working. I'm curious what kernel-changes might trigger this behaviour (if I'm correct)...

Comment: There has been some development in rebase, it might be that the list it is made by C code now, but just some year ago the rebase was pure shell script. You could install some older git and see if it reproduces, and if it is then check low-level commands which  make the list

Comment: Given the really odd behavior, I suspect it's not Git per se, but perhaps some bizarre interaction between your C library and your kernel. I'd start by gathering system call traces to see what's actually happening at that level.

Comment: For reference: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/issue-with-4-12-1-kernel-and-git/27809 - Seems to have been a regression in 4.12 kernel which seems to have been fixed at least with 4.13.